# Making operations atomic without using max_execution_time

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, atomic

I have set up a cron job (PHP script), which does the following job :

```
1. Read all of the unseen emails, using imap
   1.1  For each email readed
   1.2. Fetches the details and save detail in database
   1.3. Moves email to other mailbox named "Processed"
   1.4. Goto step 1.1
```

But If the PHP script **stops or fails** executing, **after step 1.2 but before 1.3**, the emails will be ***re-processed***, which is the *problem* here.

As we all know, the processing time depends on many factors such as server load and the number of emails to be processed, so I don't think that setting up max_execution_time will help.

How do I make this atomic? Any ideas? (I can change the process flow too, if you have any ideas about a different process flow).

**Edit:** Suppose that the email moved, and it was just going to commit, but the PHP script stops? What would happen then is that the email would move without a record being stored.

Answer (score 0):

You could put step 1.2 into a database transaction, then if step 1.3 fails, you would rollback the transaction.

If you have a transaction, and a "commit" is not explicitly called (ie via timeout, or you just forgot to call commit), then it is automatically assumed to rollback.

Comment: But "moving the email" is not a database operation. How that will be rolledback? And when the next time script will be executed, It wouldn't have any knowledge about what happened last time....

Comment: Are you saying that the email gets moved, but PHP dies before it gets notification of that moves completion?

Comment: But suppose that the email moved, and it was just going to commit, but php script stops? What will happen now is, email moves but no record stored

Comment: You might need to store a "pending" state from 1.2, then the next time your program runs, it checks the "pending" ones to see if they moved or not.  You would not need a transaction for this.